# Orchard: New widget isn't available to be added to zone

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm working with Orchard 1.1.30

I created a MapPart per [this](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Writing-a-content-part.ashx) Orchard documentation link, then converted it to a widget by [this](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Writing-a-widget.ashx) link. The first creates a content part that can then be included with different content types. This behaved as expected. The second procedure converts that content part to a widget. The first procedure is, more or less, a pre-requisite for the second.

The Maps module compiles, but when I attempt to add a widget to any zone, the Map widget is not even an option. I understood it would become an option after adding this migration:

```
public int UpdateFrom1()
{
    // Create a new widget content type with our map
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MapWidget", cfg => cfg
        .WithPart("MapPart")
        .WithPart("WidgetPart")
        .WithPart("CommonPart")
        // Shouldn't this behavior create an available widget?
        .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));

    return 2;
}
```

The `UpdateFrom1` update was successful--still too new at Orchard to guess what might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by running the migration again, only naming it `UpdateFrom2` and returning `3`. Reporting indicates this migration was run both times, but only the second time produced the desired results.

Something must have changed between the first migration and the first attempt to add the widget to a zone???